# Given $X ~$ exponential(1) r.v. Define $Y\sim$ as the integer part of $X+1$, solve for the distribution of $Y$ and derive the conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, transformation

$$Y=[X+1]=i+1$$ iff $$i\le X \lt i+1,i=0,1,....$$

My approach to derive the distribution of  $Y$ is to look at

> $P(Y=y)=P(Y\le y)-P(Y\le y-1)$

Usually, I am ok to find $g^{-1}$ given $Y=g(X)$ but for this question, I am not sure how to find the inverse of $Y=[X+1]$.

So I looked at $Y=1 $, $P([X+1]=1)$ $\Rightarrow$ $P(0<X<1)$...
And then extend it to when $Y=i$... which is $P(Y=i)=$so basically I am trying to find the pattern when solving for the inverse from $Y$ to $X$... What I found is that $P(Y\le i)=P(X<i)$.

I am wondering if there are other ways to solve the problem?

To continue:

> $P(Y=y)=P(Y\le y)-P(Y \le y-1)=P(X<y)-P(X<y-1)=e^y-e^{-(y-1)}$ for
>   $y=1,2,...$

The second question asks me to derive conditional distribution $P(X-4|y\geq 5)$ and I am completely lost.

My attempt is to use $$\frac{P(X-4,Y\geq5)}{P(Y\geq5)}$$ but I don't know what's the joint distribution of X and Y....

Comment: I suspect a typo: $P(X-4\mid y\geq5)$ cannot be recognized as a conditional probability. Do mean something like e.g. $P(X>4\mid Y\geq5)$?

Comment: @drhab Sorry, I have modified the question. It's conditional distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the first question: nothing is wrong with stating that:$$Y=n\iff n-1\leq X<n\text{ for }n=1,2,\dots$$so that also:$$P(Y=n)= P(n-1\leq X<n)\text{ for }n=1,2,\dots$$

Working this out leads to: $$P(Y=n)=P(X<n)-P(X<n-1)=(1-e^{-n})-(1-e^{-(n-1)})=e^{-n+1}-e^{-n}$$
for $n=1,2,\dots$

---

Note that $Y\geq5\iff X\geq4$ so that:$$P(X-4\geq x\mid Y\geq5)P(X\geq 4)=P(X-4\geq x\mid X\geq4)P(X\geq 4)=$$$$P(X-4\geq x, X\geq4)=P(X\geq\max(4,4+x))$$

Here $P(X\geq4)=e^{-4}$ and for RHS we discern:

- $x<0$ then $P(X\geq\max(4,4+x))=P(X\geq4)>0$ and leading to $$P(X-4\geq x\mid Y\geq5)=1$$
- $x\geq0$ then $P(X\geq\max(4,4+x))=P(X\geq4+x)=e^{-4+x}$ and leading to:$$P(X-4\geq x\mid Y\geq5)=e^{-x}$$

Actually this can be found more directly on base of [memorylessness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution#Memorylessness) of [exponential distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution) stating that $P(X>s+t\mid X>s)=P(X>t)$.